# Regular expression with two different patterns in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl and I have the following problem:

Given a text, which consists of of words und usual punctuation, I would like to write a regular expression which searches for words on the one hand and special characters on the other hand. A word is either a sequence of letters ([A-Za-z]) or a sequence of printable letters but a mixture of both is not allowed. It may not have control characters.

The regular expression should have the following syntax:

```
regexp -all -inline {[A-Za-z]+ .......} $Text
```

I do not know how to write correctly the search pattern {......}.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say 'printable letters' do you perhaps mean punctuation?

Comment: No control characters, OK, but what about whitespace? Some sample input is needed.

Comment: Whitespace must be excluded. Printable letters are the printable characters from ASCII table. So a 'word' is either 1) a sequence of letters or 2) a sequence of characters which are printable characters but they are not letters and they are not control characters. Additionally to 2): Whitespace must be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

If my guess that by 'printable letters' you actually mean punctuation is correct, you could use:

```
regexp -all -inline {[[:alpha:]]+|[[:punct:]]+} $Text
```

See the documentation at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.html#M31

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! 'Printable letters' means the printable characters (ASCII) but without space and control characters. I do not know how to remove the set of letters from the character class [:graph:]. I would like to have a character class like:  [:graph:]without [A-Za-z].

Comment: Sorry but this makes no sense.  "Printable characters" obviously includes the letters [A-Za-z], but you seem to want some set of characters which is disjoint from that.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear at this point. I have to clarify it: A 'word' is either 1) a sequence of letters ([A_Za-z])   or   2) it is a sequence of characters which are neither letters nor control characters but they are contained in the character class [:graph:]. And there is an additional condition: Whitespace must be excluded as well. I do not know how to formulate the second condition inside a regular expression. In case that I cannot use the syntax [:graph:], how can I formulate condition 2 in terms of character codes (that is: \nn syntax or \mmm syntax or Unicode escape sequence \unnnn)?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Through experimentation, I've found that</strike>

```
[:graph:] == [:alnum:] + [:punct:]
```

So

```
[:graph:] - [:alpha:] == [:digit:] + [:punct:]
```

---

Unfortunately, while that's true for bash regular expressions ([ref](https://github.com/glennj/exercism.io/blob/main/_mentor_notes/bash.md#exploring-character-classes)), it's not true for Tcl: there are several characters (including `=` and `+`) that are in `[:graph:]` but not `[:punct:]`

We need a larger negative char class

```
set letters {[[:alpha:]]+}
set graph_non_letters {[^[:cntrl:][:alpha:][:space:]]+}
```

Then

```
regexp -all -inline "(?:$letters)|(?:$graph_non_letters)" $line
```

Using non-capturing parentheses to tidy the output.

---

Demo:

```
% set line {[:graph:] == [:alnum:] + [:punct:]}
[:graph:] == [:alnum:] + [:punct:]
%  regexp -all -inline "(?:$letters)|(?:$graph_non_letters)" $line
{[:} graph :\] == {[:} alnum :\] + {[:} punct :\]
```

---

Some code to inspect which classes a character resides in:

```
proc output {data} {
    set fmt [join [lrepeat [llength $data] {%-6s}]]
    puts [format $fmt {*}$data]
}

set cs {alpha alnum upper lower digit xdigit space blank punct cntrl graph print}
set rs [lmap c $cs {format {[[:%s:]]} $c}]

for {set ascii 0} {$ascii < 128} {incr ascii} {
    if {$ascii % 32 == 0} then {output [list ascii char {*}$cs]}
    set char [format {%c} $ascii]
    set results [lmap r $rs {expr {[regexp -- $r $char] ? "Y" : "."}}]
    output [list $ascii $char {*}$results]
}
```

```
ascii  char   alpha  alnum  upper  lower  digit  xdigit space  blank  punct  cntrl  graph  print 
0            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
1            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
2            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
3            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
4            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
5            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
6            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
7            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
8            .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
9             .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .     
10     
      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .      Y      .      .     
11           .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .      Y      .      .     
12           .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .      Y      .      .     
13     
      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .      Y      .      .     
14           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
15           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
16           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
17           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
18           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
19           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
20           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
21           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
22           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
23           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
24           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
25           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
26           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
27           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
28           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
29           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
30           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
31           .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .     
ascii  char   alpha  alnum  upper  lower  digit  xdigit space  blank  punct  cntrl  graph  print 
32            .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      Y     
33     !      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
34     "      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
35     #      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
36     $      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
37     %      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
38     &      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
39     '      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
40     (      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
41     )      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
42     *      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
43     +      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
44     ,      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
45     -      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
46     .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
47     /      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
48     0      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
49     1      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
50     2      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
51     3      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
52     4      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
53     5      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
54     6      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
55     7      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
56     8      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
57     9      .      Y      .      .      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
58     :      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
59     ;      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
60     <      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
61     =      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
62     >      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
63     ?      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
ascii  char   alpha  alnum  upper  lower  digit  xdigit space  blank  punct  cntrl  graph  print 
64     @      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
65     A      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
66     B      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
67     C      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
68     D      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
69     E      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
70     F      Y      Y      Y      .      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
71     G      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
72     H      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
73     I      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
74     J      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
75     K      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
76     L      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
77     M      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
78     N      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
79     O      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
80     P      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
81     Q      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
82     R      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
83     S      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
84     T      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
85     U      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
86     V      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
87     W      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
88     X      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
89     Y      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
90     Z      Y      Y      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
91     [      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
92     \      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
93     ]      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
94     ^      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
95     _      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
ascii  char   alpha  alnum  upper  lower  digit  xdigit space  blank  punct  cntrl  graph  print 
96     `      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
97     a      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
98     b      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
99     c      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
100    d      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
101    e      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
102    f      Y      Y      .      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
103    g      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
104    h      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
105    i      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
106    j      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
107    k      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
108    l      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
109    m      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
110    n      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
111    o      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
112    p      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
113    q      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
114    r      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
115    s      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
116    t      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
117    u      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
118    v      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
119    w      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
120    x      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
121    y      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
122    z      Y      Y      .      Y      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
123    {      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
124    |      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
125    }      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      Y      Y     
126    ~      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      Y     
127          .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      Y      .      .
```

Comment: Many thanks!! Your code works perfectly well. I get precisely the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: @TheoreticalPhysics if your question has been answered adequately you should Accept one of those answers.

Answer (score 1):

The non-alphabetic characters are a bit scattered in the character set, which makes writing a regular expression for them a bit annoying. There is `[[:graph:]]`, but that also matches `[[:alpha:]]` which you want something else doing with. In this case, I'd use a negative lookahead one character wide (`(?![[:alpha]])`) to constrain an immediately following `[[:graph::]]` so that the unwanted characters aren't matched; those need to be surrounded in (non-capturing) parens so the `+` afterwards applies correctly.

Composing things:

```
set RE {[[:alpha:]]+|(?:(?![[:alpha:]])[[:graph:]])+}
regexp -all -inline $RE $Text
```

Testing interactively looks OK:

```
% regexp -all -inline $RE "One 2 {three}, four 56"
One 2 \{ three \}, four 56
```

Comment: Large lookaheads can be a big performance problem, but in this case it should be fine as it is strictly one character.

Comment: It uses `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]` because the world isn't just ASCII.

Comment: Thank you! I have just tested your code and it does the job correctly. Thanks again!