# regular expression in tcl 8.0 (character classes are not allowed!)

Tags: tcl

I am working with an old version of tcl, namely tcl 8.0.

Unfortunately, this version does not support character classes like [:alpha:] or [:graph:]. Given a text, I would like to apply a regular expression on it such that every word is filled into a list:

```
set list [regexp -all -inline {[:alpha:]+|.......}]
```

A 'word' is either a sequence of letters (here I cannot use [:alpha:]!) or a sequence of printable characters in the ASCII table which are neither letters nor control characters. Whitespace must be excluded as well. (Letters like ä, ü, ö must be included!!)

I have posted this question here [Regular expression with two different patterns in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530846/regular-expression-with-two-different-patterns-in-tcl) and I received good answers. All of them work very well! But now it turned out that my code has to run under tcl 8.0 and the above answers do not work under this version because they essentially make use of character classes.

I know that I have to use character codes like \nn or \mmm syntax or the Unicode escape sequence \unnnn (I think this is expected) but I am not familiar with this kind of notation.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I feel your pain. I once worked on an object database system that had an embedded Tcl 8.0 interpreter. That was 15 years ago however.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Tcl 8.0 `regexp` man page](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/regexp.htm). There are far fewer options for the command, so more programming is required

```
set re(alpha) {[A-Za-z]+}
set re(other_graph) {[!-@[-`\{-~]+}   ;# refer to `man ascii` on your system

set line {[:graph:] == [:alnum:] + [:punct:]}
set words {}

while {1} {
    if {! [regexp -indices "($re(alpha))|($re(other_graph))" $line -> i1 i2]} {
        break
    }

    foreach {a b} $i1 break
    if {$a == -1} then {foreach {a b} $i2 break}

    lappend words [string range $line $a $b]
    set line [string range $line [expr {$b + 1}] end]
}

foreach word $words {puts $word}
```

outputs

```
[:
graph
:]
==
[:
alnum
:]
+
[:
punct
:]
```

That does not handle accented characters. Since the 8.0 regex engine is so "primitive", I don't think you have a choice but to list the wanted accented characters individually.

Alternately, you can tell your boss "I need better tools to solve these requirements".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code was very helpful. Yes, I have included the required accented characters individually.